# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un elemento HTML con Javascript a través del valor de su data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dataset

Deseo obtener un elemento del DOM pero a través del valor de su data-attribute usando JS. Usando Dataset obtengo el valor del data-attribute, pero yo necesito capturar el elemento del DOM, no su valor.

```
<div data-nombre="cuadro-user-alonso">
```

Sé que puedo hacerlo fácilmente con su "id" a través del document.getElementById(); pero yo requiero hacerlo con el valor de su data-attribute.

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar corchetes para buscar con `document.querySelector` el atributo que quieras

```
 document.querySelector('[data-nombre="cuadro-user-alonso"]')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho! :)